# different modal getting the different result for the same query sql

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I don't know what's wrong with the code, but i get the different result for the same query.

My select query (in the controller):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('vendor_location');
$query = $this->db->get();
$data['location'] = $query->result_array();
```

My partial view (modal bootstrap):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add_driver_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">ADD DRIVER</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" id='add'>
                <div class="row" id="add_driver_form">

                <?php var_dump($location);?>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick=add_driver()>Add</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="form_submit_result"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

<!-- Edit driver modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="edit_driver_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">EDIT DRIVER</h4>
              </div>
              <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>portal/edit_driver">
              <div class="modal-body" id='add'>
                <div class="row" id="edit_driver_form">

                    <?php var_dump($location);?>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Save</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

When I `var_dump($location)` in the `add_driver_modal`, I get the expected result (all records from `vendor_location` table). But I just get the last record (one row) in the `edit_driver_modal`. How could this happen?

Comment: try with this `$data['location'] = $query->result_array();
$data['location2'] = $data['location'];` use location2 for `edit_driver_modal`

Comment: aww thanks a lot ! I didn't think about that. How could that happen? @devpro

Comment: maybe your logic is also working, instead of `var_dump()` use `echo count($location)` on both location, test it and i also suggest to move your business logic / Query into modal...

Comment: maybe it just because of var_dump, did u tested?

Comment: waiting for your feedback, your response will fruitful for future visitor

Comment: yes, thank you. It's working good with the new variable `$data['location2']`

Comment: this is good to know